# Firebase Service Accounts Private Key - Does a new key add or replace?

Tags: firebase, private-key, service-accounts

**MY SITUATION**

I'm working with Firebase and looking to utilize a Service Account Private Key to access the data (Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts -> Generate New Private Key).

**MY QUESTION**:

If I generate and download a new Key, will that replace a currently used key or will I have multiple keys active? Perhaps I'm not using the right keywords to search, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who may come across this in the future...I currently have two keys generated the same way. Both work. Thus, it seems to ADD keys not replace them. I don't know if there is a limit.

Comment: I concur with you. Having just generated another Service Account Private Key and  tested with my App it looks like we now appear to have two working private key json files.  Kind of begs the question what to do if one of them ever got compromised.

Answer (score 7):

Generating a new Service Account private key **will not** replace any old ones. It will add a new private key leaving all old keys enabled and active.

In order to find all the private keys (and manage them), do the following:

1. Open **Google Cloud** console, go to the Service Accounts page
2. Select a project
3. Click the email address of the service account that is connected to the Firebase account (it usually starts with "firebase-adminsdk")
4. Click the Keys tab
5. You will see a list of keys with the ability to remove or add a new one

You can see [more details in here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#creating), it explains how to create a new key from Google Cloud console that leads to the exact place where you can see all private keys.